# Is it possible to block all content uploaded from some location from appearing?

Tags: firewall, parental-controls

Like for example to stop videos on sites such as YouTube which were uploaded from some country from appearing. or even block sites which are hosted from a particular country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to block all content uploaded from some location from appearing?

Maybe? This likely depends on:

- What your definition of "uploaded" is.
- If you control one or more servers, proxies or networks.
- The software you use (in any context).
- How dedicated you are to blocking things (in terms of creating lists of undesirable domains/IPs or blocking entire TLDs).

> For example, can I stop videos on sites such as YouTube which were uploaded from some country from appearing?

There is no public information (as far as I am aware) that directly links the content provided by YouTube to an original source IP. This is true of other video sharing sites as well.

But if you mean "uploaded" as in "loaded from a particular domain or IP range when served to a browser" (which would not be the "original" IP of the uploader but part of e.g. Google's distribution system), blocking that content *might* be possible with proxy software or browser adblockers.

> Is it possible to block sites which are hosted from a particular country?

Likely yes, assuming you mean "physically hosted" (where the final servers delivering the content are actually located) or by domain names/TLDs. This would, again, be done through proxy or adblocking software (or the like) in most instances.